# libgdx: asset manager block screen ui

Tags: android, libgdx

I use `AssetManager` to load all assets in my game. 
I have problem with displaying loading progress or instead progress I try to set only background colour using this code in my LoadingScreen render method.

```
    Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.431f, 0.792f, 0.808f, 0xff / 255.0f);
    Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
```

Everiting loads well but, while loading I get black screen instead  colour set in glClearColor. The same happend when implementing loading bar like [this](https://github.com/Matsemann/libgdx-loading-screen/tree/libgdx1.2.0-EyeOfMidas) example

Here part of `Assests` class

```
    public class Assets implements Disposable, AssetErrorListener {

        public static final Assets instance = new Assets();
      .
      .
        public void init (AssetManager assetManager) {
            this.assetManager = assetManager;
        // set asset manager error handler
        assetManager.setErrorListener(this);
        // load texture atlas
        assetManager.load(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS, TextureAtlas.class);
     .
     .
        TextureAtlas atlas = assetManager.get(Constants.TEXTURE_ATLAS_OBJECTS);
     .


   }  
     .


}
```

Here is simple code of my `LoadingScreen`:

```
    @Override
    public void show() {
        manager = new AssetManager();

        Assets.instance.init(manager);
   }

    public void render(float deltaTime) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0.431f, 0.792f, 0.808f, 0xff / 255.0f);//light blue
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

        if (manager.update()) {
            ScreenTransition transition = ScreenTransitionFade.init(0.5f);
            game.setScreen(new HomeScreen(game), transition);
        }
}
```

Here I expected light blue empty screen to show while loading assets, but I get black screen.

I guess some code blocks main thread but I don't know how to fix this.

Thanks for help

Comment: The "cleaning" part is OK, probably the problem is somewhere else. IF you remove the code after the cleaning part is working [do you have a non black screen ? ] ?

Comment: `Assets.instance.init(manager);` blocks my UI.If I remove the code after the cleaning part its the same (black screen while loading). Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you know when `Screen.show()` and `Screen.render(float delta)` are called:

`Screen.show()`: is called when you call `Game.setScreen()`.

`Screen.render(float delta)`: is called continuously **after** `Screen.show()` is finished. Hence during the loading `Screen.show()` is not yet finished and the default background (black) is shown.

To avoid that a separate thread would be nice. Here comes `AssetManager` which loads stuff asynchronously. Now we only have use it properly:

Call `AssetManager.load(<your assets>)` **before** you call `Game.setScreen(<Loading Screen>)`. `LoadingScreen.render(float delta)` is then called directly and you see your background. To check if the loading is done you can use `AssetManager.update()`, which returns true if done and false else.

Comment: thanks, I call `setScreen(LoadingScreen)` in `public class MyGame extends DirectedGame {}`. If I call `Assets.instance.init(manager);` on ` create()` in MyGame class where to check if assets are loaded(`update()`)? In LoadingScreen `update()` method? I try this but not working again, not I think black screen is displayed in `MyGame` class

Comment: In my implementations I check `AssetManager.update()` in `LoadingScreeen.render()` and switch to the new screen if all loading is done.

Comment: where you call `Assets.instance.init(manager);` ? in LoadingScreen? tnx

Comment: I would call `.init()` right before the setScreen(loadingScreen). I think I know what your problem is: `assetManager.load()` loads your stuff asynchronously. But the rest of the `.init()` method, need this stuff to be loaded and hence waits until loading is finished. I would suggest that you restrucutre your `init()` method that it only contains asynchronous loading stuff. Then in your render method you check for the `assetManager.update()` until loading is finished and then allocate your `TextureAtlas`. For a detailed analysis, I need to see complete `.init()` method.